# CV2 save image with keypoint

Tags: python, image, opencv

Is there a way to save an image with the keypoints overlaid?

eg. after using blob detection i get this image:
[image]

Is there a way to save this image such that when loaded it has the red circles overlaid.
for example something along the lines of

```
cv2.saveWindow("CountedImage.png", window)
```

where CountedImage.png has the red circles overlaid.

Comment: so if red circles are drawn in the image, imwrite it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do your Blob Detection you can simply do something like:

```
import cv2

"""
   Your blob detection code
"""

cv2.imshow("Blob Detected ", result_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Save the result figure
cv2.imwrite('result.png',result_image)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: sorry for the dv., but please do not recommend to **mix** opencv and matplotlib, as this will try to save an bgr image in rgb channel order